# Bag of Words - SVM Classification - reg

Tags: opencv

I'm doing an Object detection & Recognition concept in OpenCV C++.

I'm using the BOW API available in OpenCV.

The classifier used is SVM.

Number of Object classes was set to 20. Number of Images for training was set to 50.

I'm using SVM Classifier.

The code is here. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/619039/Bag-of-Features-Descriptor-on-SIFT-Features-with-O

But the classification rate is poor. How can I improve?

How to select number of images for training for each object?

How to select the dictionary size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can find all information you asking for here: http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/pubs/everingham10.pdf

Comment: The link is dead do you have any other line or new one?